# Command objects and DTOs, difference?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails

When we speak of command objects in Grails and even in Spring, are they the same as data transfer objects? Meaning, is a command object an example of the implementation of the DTO enterprise design pattern? If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A **data transfer object (DTO)** is an object (simple java bean) that carries data between any two layers or processes. You might generally introduce/use DTO layer & populate the DTO bean with the data received from an external web service or external system. Refer [Martin Fowler's blog on Data Transfer Object](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) for more details

**Command object** is just a **spring (mvc) terminology which maps the html form data to a java bean (form bean)**. Here Spring Dispatcher servlet & helper classes map the data from html form to the java bean. In Grails, command objects do serve more than data carriers like AST transformation.

In summary, they both are data carriers from one layer to the other.

Is a command object in Spring an example of the implementation of the DTO enterprise design pattern ?

> Yes, but the point to note is that the Spring Dispatcher servlet &
>   helper classes populate the command object with html form data.

Comment: "Command object is just a spring (mvc) terminology which maps the html form data to a java bean (form bean)" - that is not true in the context of Grails, which is what the question is about.  There is a bunch of special things we do for what Grails calls "command objects" including not only data binding but also dependency injection and validation.

Comment: "...but the point to note is that the Spring Dispatcher servlet & helper classes populate the command object with html form data."  - that is not true in Grails.  We have an AST transformation that rigs up all of the data binding, dependency injection and validation logic at compile time.  The dispatcher servlet is not involved in any of that in Grails.

Comment: I got your point on Grails, but the question has combined both Spring & Grails

Comment: That is why I said "That is not true in the context of Grails"

Comment: Another advantage of using DTOs on RESTful APIs written in Java (and on Spring Boot), is that they can help hiding implementation details of domain objects (aka. entities).